# I don't know why it can run on calculation?

Tags: c

My programming is about making a water bill.I had trouble running on my calculation part and it just show 0 when i key in any data. The calculation is amount=sqrfeet*2.05; is it because of the floating part?? And i am using if else statement.

```
int main()
    { char ch;
    int a;
    float amount, sqrfeet;
    start:
    printf("\n-------------Selangor Water Bill--------------\n");
    printf("\n1.Domestic\n");
    printf("\n2.Commercial\n");
    printf("\n3.Industrial");
    printf("\nChoose one of the category:",a);
    scanf("%d",&a);
    system("CLS");
    if (a!=1&&a!=2&&a!=3){
    goto start;
    }
    if (a=1){
    printf("\n1.Domestic");
    printf("\nEnter the amount of consumption water per sqrfeet in 35days:");
    scanf("%f",&amount);
    if(sqrfeet<=35){
        amount=sqrfeet*0.57;
    }
    else if(sqrfeet>35&&sqrfeet<=50){
        amount=sqrfeet*1.03;
    }
    else if (sqrfeet>50){
        amount=sqrfeet*2.00;
    }
    printf("\nTotal Amount is RM%.2lf", amount);
    }
    else if(a=2){
    printf("\n2.Commercial");
    printf("\nEnter the amount of consumption water per sqrfeet in 
    35days:");
    scanf("%f",&amount);
    if(sqrfeet<=35){
        amount=sqrfeet*2.07;
    }
    else if(sqrfeet>35&&sqrfeet<=50){
        amount=sqrfeet*2.28;
    }
    printf("\nTotal Amount is RM%.2lf", amount);
    }
    else if (a=3){
    printf("\n3.Industrial");
    printf("\nEnter the amount of consumption water per sqrfeet in 35days:");
    scanf("%f",&amount);
    if(sqrfeet<=35){
        amount=sqrfeet*2.49;
    }
    else if(sqrfeet>35&&sqrfeet<=50){
        amount=sqrfeet*2.70;
    }
    printf("\nTotal Amount is RM%.2lf", amount);
    }

    printf("\nPress'q' to quit ");
    scanf("%c",&ch);
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Lastly please read [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: And on a couple of unrelated notes: Don't use `goto` instead of loops; When using `printf` use *trailing* newlines instead of leading.

Comment: `=` is assignment, `==` is for checking equality.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why trailing newlines instead of leading?

Comment: @Broman A trailing new line will likely flush the output to the screen rather than staying stuck in a buffered `stdout`.  Flushing after output is   more common than before.

Comment: `goto` tip:  `goto` has its place (rarely), but never for a learner.  Do not use `goto` until you understand why.  Research `while, do for`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the problem is this line

```
scanf("%f",&amount);
```

I assume that you want it like this

```
scanf("%f",&sqrfeet);
```

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know why it can run on calculation?

Either the compiler is weak or warnings are not fully enabled.

**Save time and enable all warnings** and receive ones like the below.  This will help locate many, though not all, problems.

```
// gcc example
gcc -std=c11 -O3 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -c ...
```

---

> warning: suggest parentheses around assignment used as truth value [-Wparentheses]

```
 if (a = 1) {
```

The compiler sees this *assignment* and suggests `if ((a = 1)) {` to quiet the warning. Yet OP certainly does not want an assignment here, but a compare. [@dbush](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53361852/hi-guys-i-need-help-i-dont-know-why-it-can-run-on-calculation/53362447#comment93600336_53361852)

```
 if (a == 1) {
```

---

> warning: 'sqrfeet' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Code is using `sqrfeet` before it is assigned. Certainly `scanf("%f",&sqrfeet);` was desired. [@Tomek Piechocki](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53361893/2410359)

```
// scanf("%f",&amount);
scanf("%f",&sqrfeet);
if(sqrfeet<=35){
```

---

> warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]

The `printf()` call is mal-formed.

```
// printf("\nChoose one of the category:", a);
printf("\nChoose one of the category:");
```

---

> warning: conversion to 'float' from 'double' may alter its value [-Wfloat-conversion]

`0.57` is a `double`. No reason to use `float` for typical floating point math.  Use `double`.  Save `float` for large arrays or timing critical concerns.

```
// float amount, sqrfeet;
//scanf("%f", &amount);
double amount, sqrfeet;
scanf("%lf", &amount);

amount = sqrfeet * 0.57;
```

If you want to stay with `float`, use a `float` constant: `0.57f`.

---

Also: all `scanf()` specifiers consume leading white-space except, `c, [, n`.  Add a space to consume the prior input line's left-over `'\n'` (<kbd>Enter</kbd>).

```
// scanf("%c",&ch);
//     v
scanf(" %c",&ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int main()
{ char ch;
int a;
float amount, sqrfeet;
start:
printf("\n-------------Selangor Water Bill--------------\n");
printf("\n1.Domestic\n");
printf("\n2.Commercial\n");
printf("\n3.Industrial");
printf("\nChoose one of the category:",a);
scanf("%d",&a);
system("CLS");
if (a!=1&&a!=2&&a!=3){
goto start;
}
if (a=1){
printf("\n1.Domestic");
printf("\nEnter the amount of consumption water per sqrfeet in 35days:");
scanf("%f",&sqrfeet); // Change made here
if(sqrfeet<=35){
    amount=sqrfeet*0.57;
}
else if(sqrfeet>35&&sqrfeet<=50){
    amount=sqrfeet*1.03;
}
else if (sqrfeet>50){
    amount=sqrfeet*2.00;
}
printf("\nTotal Amount is RM%.2lf", amount);
}
else if(a=2){
printf("\n2.Commercial");
printf("\nEnter the amount of consumption water per sqrfeet in 
35days:");
scanf("%f",&sqrfeet); // Change made here
if(sqrfeet<=35){
    amount=sqrfeet*2.07;
}
else if(sqrfeet>35&&sqrfeet<=50){
    amount=sqrfeet*2.28;
}
printf("\nTotal Amount is RM%.2lf", amount);
}
else if (a=3){
printf("\n3.Industrial");
printf("\nEnter the amount of consumption water per sqrfeet in 35days:");
scanf("%f",&sqrfeet); // Change made here
if(sqrfeet<=35){
    amount=sqrfeet*2.49;
}
else if(sqrfeet>35&&sqrfeet<=50){
    amount=sqrfeet*2.70;
}
printf("\nTotal Amount is RM%.2lf", amount);
}

printf("\nPress'q' to quit ");
scanf("%c",&ch);
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several issues:

1. You never assign a value to `sqrfeet`, so all your computations with `sqrfeet` are going to be bad.  You probably want a separate `scanf` statement to read that when you also read `amount`.

   Your `if` statements are using `=` (assignment) instead of `==` (comparison), which is re-assigning `a`.  Instead of `if ( a = 1 )` use `if ( a == 1 )`.

   While it’s not the cause of your problem, avoid using `goto` when possible.  Your input loop can be better written as

   ```
   int a = -1; // initialize a to a known bad value
   do
   {
     // print menu options

     /**
      * Check the result of scanf - if it isn't 1, then the the
      * user entered non-numeric input.  Clear the bad input up
      * to the next newline before trying again.
      */
     if ( scanf("%d", &a ) != 1 )  
       while ( getchar() != '\n' )
         ; 

   } while ( a < 1 && a > 3 );
   ```